# Type backtick on windows italian keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

How can I type a backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>) or tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) using my Italian keyboard on Windows 8?

Right now, I'm using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>.  Are there any other key combinations?

Comment: Maybe, I found the solution:  
http://sdrv.ms/16LZN8N

You will install this keyboard, then remove any keyboard in control panel except this new keyboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe, this is the best solution:

[ITA-Dev Keyboard - Italian keyboard for developers](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArqXUvKZFFNH70KlRzmg1fmF4e_K?e=a3eWg9)

Install this keyboard, then remove any keyboard in Control Panel except this new keyboard.
Now you can type these chars:

```
` (AltGr + ')
~ (AltGr + ì)
À (AltGr + shift + a)
È (AltGr + shift + e)
Ì (AltGr + shift + i)
Ò (AltGr + shift + o)
Ù (AltGr + shift + u)
® (AltGr + r) registered
© (AltGr + c) copyright
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my **DELL** laptop italian keyboard.

Comment: @gsscoder, maybe now you have the opportunity to change the current Keyboard in traybar. Then, select "ITA" instead of "ITA-IT".

Comment: I've properly configured it via **Time & language -> Keyboard** but the icon deosn't appear in the traybar. I can't spot why. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided link is broken.

Comment: @riofly You are welcome! Thank you, now it is working correctly.

Comment: @Andrea I'm happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Tilde is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>126</kbd> for normal one (~), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>152</kbd>` for small one (˜)

You can find other codes here [link](http://heraultetplus.com/files/CharacterCodes.htm)

Comment: In my Windows 10 workstation with standard Italian layout I use [Alt] + [126] for normal tilde `~` and [Alt] + [96] for backtick `` ` ``, which is consistent with the link you provide. Using [Alt] + [152] instead of a small tilde I get this: `ÿ`. By the way, your answer definitely deserves an upvote because it is the only one not requiring installing software with admin permissions (impossible when using common workstations in a company).