# xrdp: curly braces on Italian keyboards (i.e. AltGr + Shift + key not working)

Tags: remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I installed xrdp on a Ubuntu machine (following [this](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4448)), which works fine except for a problem with the keymap.

On Italian keyboard, you can type curly braces ("{" and "}") by typing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>è</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, respectively (see picture below, taken from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/667622/italian-keyboard-entering-the-tilde-and-backtick-characters-without-cha)). The "è" and "+" characters do not need any key combination, you just press the corresponding key.

[image: Italian keyboard layout]

While this works fine on XFCE4 with the physically connected keyboard, this doesn't work when connecting through remote desktop using xrdp (I've experienced this problem using both Windows' Remote Desktop and rdesktop).

When connected through the remote session, the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key works fine per se: for example, I can type square brackets, which are <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>è</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. It seems the problem is when combining <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I've tried editing/regenerating the km-0410.ini file (describing the keymap for xrdp) as according to [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858), but nothing worked.

All suggestions and ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since I'm new to Linux VM i had this problem too, and I solved the problem (I'm Italian too)

In my case my config is:
Ubuntu Server 16.04 => with GNOME desktop, and XRDP

i had to change the keyboard as you tried, the problem is that like you I ended up with a wrong (incomplete and screwed) km-0410.ini file

In this article there is a link to download a pack with fixed .ini files
http://eurekamoment.eu/?p=144 (so i guess this would solve even other languages problems)

I just replaced the km-0410.ini file in that zip with the one in my /etc/xrdp/ folder and restarted xrdp, and now i can RDP with my Windows client, to the GNOME server with correct keyboard, finally!

hope this could help others in trouble

Comment: Hi Fabio. Do you have a copy of that file because the domain is no more active.

Comment: mmm i should see if i find it on my VM, anyway this is the post of the author of the file, that explain what he did: http://component-parts.blogspot.it/2012/08/fixing-uk-keyboard-mapping-for-xrdp.html

Answer (score -1):

On MacOS with an italian keyboard layout, to get curly brackets,
you have type

**option + shift + è**

and

**option + shift + +**