# How to change some key mapping on keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm on italian keyboard, accessing ` and ~ is so frustrating (I have to enter alt 96 and alt 126), but I have also a useless § key (shift + ù). What I'd like to do is to "add a layer" to \ key so pressing altgr + \ will produce ~  and altgr + ' will make `

Another nice thing to add is support for "dead key", what I'd like is to have single pressure to behaving as usual and (altgr + shift) + pressure let it behave as dead key.

So to put *e'* I just enter *e + '*, to enter *é* I enter *altgr + shift + '*  then *e*.

Can someone please suggest me a solution?

NOTE: switching to IT-104 is not an option as it remaps ~ to ] so I'll gain the gliphs but at cost of losing another that was well memorized.

Comment: I suggest following the pattern of [this answer using AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/a/1201938/206587)

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t mind doing e.g., <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for **é** (just the reverse of what you suggest above), then you can set your keyboard to US-International. That will make <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>^</kbd> into dual-use dead keys, where if you follow any of them with a character than can carry the accent (usually a vowel, but also <kbd>N</kbd> for <kbd>~</kbd> (**Ñ**) and <kbd>C</kbd> for <kbd>'</kbd> (**Ç**)), you’ll get the accented character. If you want the punctuation only, follow the accent with a space - that is, <kbd>`</kbd>+      will give you **`**.

Comment: True, but punctuation and special characters is totally messed up  in US layout (where you have ; I have @, and so on) US layout is not an option

Comment: If a US layout is unacceptable, then your only real alternative will be a hack like AutoHotKey, as @davidmneedham suggests in the comments.

Comment: I made a custom layouut with Windows tool, it's fine!