# How to write < or > on an ANSI keyboard with Estonian EST ET language?

Tags: keyboard, asus, symbols

I recently bought Asus Rog with a US ANSI keyboard. It doesn't have a < > button between the Z and shift buttons. How can I write < or > on this keyboard using an Estonian EST ET keyboard layout?

Image of the keyboard

[image]

Comment: Clarifying what EST ET means might help. A picture of it might help too. Not having that key doesn't tell us what it **does** have… whether it's an international ISO or an ANSI...

Comment: EST ET is an Estonian language keyboard. I will add image of the keyboard to the post. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it easier. I don't know precisely how to find it, but everyone now can now see what you have is a US keyboard, with an ANSI layout.

Comment: You could just open the keyboard viewer & press alt or shift & see if you can spot them.

Comment: Then the < > button is between Z and shift but I don't have it on the keyboard.

Comment: The keyboard viewer should mirror your actual keyboard. ANSI keyboards don’t have that extra key.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Nmkj07s

I don't have a key between shift and z on my phyiscal keyboard

Comment: Correct. You bought an American ANSI keyboard. The onscreen viewer should still be aware of both your layout & language setting.

Comment: Is there any other way I can still use EST ET keyboard and write lesser than and greater than symbol?

Comment: create your own keyboard layout with MSKLC: [Italian keyboard: entering tilde (~) and backtick (`) characters without changing keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/667622/241386)

Comment: Try ALT+60 for `<` and ALT+62 for `>` but you dont have a numeric keypad so not sure if this will working

Comment: Which characters do you get when you press Shift with comma or dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Estonian keyboard is the
[variant](https://gate2home.com/Estonian-Keyboard)
where typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> gives `;`
while
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> gives `:`.
But `<` and `>` both seem totally missing, unless you use
their ALT-codes (Alt-60/62) to enter.

For a more elegant solution I suggest using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following 2-lines AutoHotkey script will map
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to `<` and
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to `>`.
This will make those keys agree with your displayed keyboard, except
that you will be using the
<kbd>Alt</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

```
!,::Send, <
!.::Send, >
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk`
file and double-click it to test. You may stop the script by
right-click on the green `H` icon in the traybar and choosing
Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Works like a charm. Binded z and x instead of . and , because it's more practical for me. !x::Send, <
!z::Send, >
Easy solution, thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Nordic and many other european keyboard layouts have an extra key between the left shift and the Z key.
You can use Keyboard Manager in the Microsoft PowerToys app on Windows.

Create a new Shortcut Mapping. Enter your desired key combination and select to send the character '<' **as text**  (not Key/Shortcut option). And add other shortcuts for other characters the same way.
For example, I created: Ctrl + Shift + ',' as shortcut for '<'.

Another way is to add the US keyboard layout in Windows and then change between keyboard layouts by pressing the Win+Space.

Answer (score -1):

Try pressing one of these with the <kbd>shift</kbd> key held down:

[image]

They are in between the 'M' and '?/' key near the right <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: These don't work with EST keyboard but they work with UK keyboard. Can't use UK language because then I don't have my native letters.